# Custom Dialog in full screen?

Tags: android, dialog, fullscreen

Is there any way to make my Dialog view full screen, i.e dialog occupy the entire screen (like an Activity). I tried using the LayoutParams and styles like
`<item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>` but nothing seems to be working.

I found a way of getting rid of the Title bar, but couldn't find a way to put a dialog in full screen. So can any one suggest me a way to do it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<style name="MyTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowFrame">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/dialog_background</item>
</style>
</resources>
```

Comment: Can you post your custom dialog xml file or custom code?

Comment: Why dont you just use `Activity`?

Comment: Your style worked for me

Answer (score 109, accepted):

Give its constructor a non-dialog theme, such as **android.R.style.Theme** or **android.R.style.Theme_Light**.

Code by @Bob.

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context, android.R.style.Theme_Light); 
dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); 
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.MyCustomDialogLayout); 
dialog.show();
```

Comment: This one works pretty cool. the Dialog is coming in full screen with out any borders. thanks...

Comment: Its great! For NoTitle fullscreen dialog I used "@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" as my dialog's theme parent.

Comment: This works great for that purpose (full screen dialog), however the cancelable property is not working anymore. Any ideas?

Comment: android.R.style.Theme_DeviceDefault_Dialog_MinWidth  use this for minimum width of device.

Answer (score 35):

Following code works in my case :

```
dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); 
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.mydialog2);
dialog.getWindow().setLayout(WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
```

Comment: I tried this one but it is not working in my code, I couldn't find the  reason why. But the [Renard](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10173576/970272) code is working perfectly.

Comment: dialog.getWindow().setLayout(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT); worked for me

Answer (score 20):

Try this

```
dialog = new Dialog(context,android.R.style.Theme_Translucent_NoTitleBar_Fullscreen);
```

Comment: F*cking thanks. Best answer so far. Worked for me (I was doing a custom subclass)

Comment: `Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);`

Answer (score 5):

1.custom your dialog style

```html
 <style name = "MyDialog" >
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
        <item name = "android:windowContentOverlay" >@null</item >
        <item name = "android:colorBackgroundCacheHint" >@null</item >
        <item name = "android:backgroundDimEnabled">true</item>
        <item name = "android:windowBackground" >@android:color/transparent</item >
    </style >
```

2 :custom your dialog

```html
WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) this.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
            int width = wm.getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();
            int height = wm.getDefaultDisplay().getHeight();
            final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this, R.style.MyDialog);
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.layout_dialog, null);

            WindowManager.LayoutParams params = dialog.getWindow().getAttributes();
            params.width = WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
            params.height = WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;

            dialog.setContentView(view);
            dialog.getWindow().setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM);
            dialog.getWindow().setWindowAnimations(R.style.mydialog_Style);
            dialog.show();
```

Comment: This is the best answer so far for me.
I tried @Renard answer, that also worked but was making the whole background of the custom dialog black. I used to set the background color to themes, but instead of changing the color according to the themes, it goes completely black.

Answer (score 3):

The answer does not work for me(sdk 21, samsung galaxy s5). After searching and testing, I find that the key point for setting a dialog for fullscreen is the `<item name="android:windowIsFloating">false</item>` in your dialog style. Most styles of Dialog in sdk set it true! Set it false in a style and use it in

```
AlertDialog.Builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity(), R.style.YourStyle);
```

your style may look like

```
<style name="YourStyle">
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">false</item>
    ...
</style>
```

after setting it false, it should be fullscreen. And more, you can use

```
dialog.getWindow.setLayout(WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
```

to set it's height to wrap_content.
Hope to help someone.

Answer (score 3):

Try wrapping your `dialog_custom_layout.xml` into `RelativeLayout` . That worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

For full screen dialog you should extend `DialogFragment` it will provide `Fragment` life cycle methods and this is the recommended way in Android developer documents you can use simple `Dialog` or `AlertDialog` also.

When you create dialog instance just use `android.R.style.Theme_Black_NoTitleBar_Fullscreen` theme with context like this :

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(getActivity(), android.R.style.Theme_Black_NoTitleBar_Fullscreen);
```

or

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity(), android.R.style.Theme_Black_NoTitleBar_Fullscreen);
```

This will show the dialog in full screen.

Answer (score 1):

try this code

```
protected void openDialog() {
        Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
        dialog.addContentView(new View(this), (new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT)));
        dialog.show();
    }
```

Comment: create a layout for your dialog and replace "new View(this)" with your layout

Comment: call this method from your activity and here "this" is the context its working fine for me

Answer (score 1):

I'm using a Activity with Dialog theme. In this case, fullscreen worked this way:

```
int mUIFlag = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION;

@Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(mUIFlag);

        getWindow().setLayout(WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        setContentView(R.layout.lockscreen_activity);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create your Custom Dialog as

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context, android.R.style.Theme_Translucent_NoTitleBar_Fullscreen);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are steps how to create a full screen dialog with custom layout which occupies the entire screen without any padding from each site.

**Step 1:** Define your custom dialog layout named `layout_fullscreen_dialog.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary">

    <!-- Your dialog content here -->

</LinearLayout>
```

**Step 2:** Define a new style in `styles.xml` named `FullScreenDialog`

```
<style name="FullScreenDialog" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

**Step 3:** Write a method which creates and shows a dialog

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        createAndShowDialog(this);
    }

    // This method used to create and show a full screen dialog with custom layout.
    public void createAndShowDialog(Context context) {
        Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context, R.style.FullScreenDialog);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.layout_fullscreen_dialog);

        WindowManager.LayoutParams layoutParams = dialog.getWindow().getAttributes();
        dialog.getWindow().setLayout(WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        dialog.getWindow().setAttributes(layoutParams);
        dialog.show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Full Screen dialog with Databinding**

```
    fun showUserQrCode(
    mContext: Activity,
    showAddMore: Boolean,
    message: String?,
    skipClick: View.OnClickListener?,
    addMoreClick: View.OnClickListener?
) {

    val dialog = Dialog(mContext, android.R.style.Theme_Black_NoTitleBar_Fullscreen)
    val discountBinding: PopupUserQrCodeBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(
        LayoutInflater.from(mContext),
        R.layout.popup_user_qr_code,
        null,
        false
    )
    discountBinding.btnSkip.setOnClickListener(skipClick)


    dialog.setContentView(discountBinding.root)
    dialog.show()
}
```

**Without Binding**

```
    val dialog = Dialog(mContext, android.R.style.Theme_Black_NoTitleBar_Fullscreen)
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.slider_layout)
    dialog.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this, android.R.style.Theme_Black_NoTitleBar_Fullscreen);
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.my_content);
dialog.show();
```

> Basically uses a non-dialog theme for dialog.
> Path in `styles.xml` would be:
> `@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen`

Answer (score 0):

In Kotlin

```
val dialog = Dialog(this, android.R.style.Theme_Light)
        dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE)
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.level_complete)
        dialog.show()
        dialog.setCancelable(false)
```