# Make Dialog occupy all screen space

Tags: android, dialog, android-dialog

I have an Android app that should show a fullscreen dialog. I've try different solution, but no one seems work. 
This is my code.
Layout of dialog:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/black_transparent" >


    <!--declaration of other widgets -->

</RelativeLayout>
```

this is  Class that extends dialog:

```
publicMyDialog(Context context) {
    super(context, R.style.DialogTheme);
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    this.setContentView(R.layout.my_dialog);
    this.setCancelable(true);
    this.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
    this.getWindow().clearFlags(LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND);

}
```

and this is R.style.DialogTheme declaration

```
<style name="DialogTheme" parent="android:Theme.Dialog">
    <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:windowFrame">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
</style>
```

Now when dialog is showed it doesn't fill all screen.
How can i do for make dialog occupy all screen?

Comment: you can represent an activity as dialog

Answer (score 0):

There are many options for this. One is set Theme for dialog i.e.

```
Dialog dialog=new Dialog(this,android.R.style.Theme_Black_NoTitleBar_Fullscreen);
```

and other is setting layout params. (You can use this in onCreateDialog() method)

```
 dialog.getWindow().setFlags(LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

Comment: In this way it's not showed my background color, but theme bg color

Answer (score 0):

Instead of deriving *DialogTheme* from parent *android.Theme.Dialog*, use a non dialog Theme as parent such as **@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar**

Answer (score 0):

You can set

```
getWindow().setLayout(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
```

Please check This for more information .I hope it will helps you .

> [Custom Dialog in full screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10173544/custom-dialog-in-full-screen)